# Functions and Files

Tags: python-2.7

please help :)
I'm learning from pythonhardway
Exercise 20:Functions and Files

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv
def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

if current line = 2 
it print the second line how ???!!!!!!!

```
def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)
```

& `**rewind(current_file)**`
why we put (f)
why not input_file ?!

i tried to explain what i think it is doing.

Sorry if i ask stupid questions :(

Comment: Here's a hint -- change `current_line = 1` to `current_line = 8675309` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you bro 8675309 first i understand know it def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline() Because we write readline() when i type it again it write the next line :)

Comment: now i need answer to the second question if you know please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues at work here.

1 -- difference between name of file and file object you can operate on

2 -- difference between parameter names in functions and values used to call those functions

When you have a file named (e.g.) `data.csv`, you can refer to it using a string:

`file_name = 'data.csv'`

... but that's just a string of characters.  To operate on the file with that name, you do:

`fh = open(file_name)`

You now have a file handle that can be used with file read, write, delete, seek etc. functions.  So the first part of your answer is, file names are not the same things as file objects; so you would call the rewind function using `current_file` (the file handle) not `input_file` (the file name).

The other issue, perhaps obvious, is the placeholder parameter you use to define a function (like `f` in your example) is just a placeholder -- when you call that function later, the value you call it with is used.

So while the function is **defined** as `rewind(f)`, when you call it later as `rewind(current_file)` you are in fact performing a seek on `current_file` -- not `f`, that's just a placeholder.

So in short -- you call `seek` (inside the function definition) using `f` because that's the placeholder / symbol name you chose to use for your reusable function (and that name could be changed to almost anything you want, in the function definition and function body) without affecting anything.  And the reason you call `rewind` using `current_file` is that is the file object you opened to work on.

Does it make sense?

Comment: i got many problems i try to fix it & know the answer with myself but this lesson was hard for me first time funtions & script working together :) sometimes i feel like I'm stupid :) Thank you broooo

Comment: That's how you learn -- keep going and don't be shy to ask for help.

Comment: i feel shy when i get downvote :( but u are right :) i hope i will be professional programmer :)

Comment: i have small question pls :)                                               iam sorry :)                                                                         def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b
get=add(5,10)                                                        the result:                                                              Age: 35   (why it didn't print adding 5+6 ? )

Comment: Try creating a new question where you can copy & paste your code with all indentation.  It looks like it should work, but you included some other details like the word "age" that aren't in your code snippet, so I have to wonder if the code you typed in here is your real code.